# Skip from penultimate item in the IEnumerable

Tags: c#

I have a `IEnumerable` (**not** `List`) like the following list :

```
A,B,C,D,E
```

With the command below, I will skip the last item (E) :

```
items_split.Take(items_split.Count() - 1);  //output : A,B,C,D
```

And with the command below, I will skip the first item (A) :

```
items_split.Skip(1); //output : B,C,D,E
```

how can i skip the *penultimate* item in the list? (desired result is `A,B,C,E`)

Note : not the last, but immediately before the last.

Comment: Looks like you need to rethink your data structure. A list is not very good at this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's exploit the fact that `items_split` is a `List<T>` - we can use `Count`:

```
var result = items_split
  .Where((value, index) => index != items_split.Count() - 2);
```

In *general case* (when `items_split` is `IEnumerable<T>` only `Count` can be too expencive or even misleasing e.g. if you query a file which can be *changed* after `Count`):

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ExcludePenultimate<T>(IEnumerable<T> source) {
  if (null == source)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));

  Queue<T> queue = new Queue<T>();

  foreach (var item in source) {
    queue.Enqueue(item);

    if (queue.Count > 2) 
      yield return queue.Dequeue();
  }

  if (queue.Count > 2)
    yield return queue.Dequeue();

  if (queue.Count == 2)
    queue.Dequeue();

  yield return queue.Dequeue();
}
```

and then

```
var result = ExcludePenultimate(items_split);
```

Comment: thanks for your response, there is a problem, Error : ` Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'int' `

Comment: @Reza Hatami: so `items_split` is not a list; if it's a materialized collection `Count()` will be enough; in general case - see my edit.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach with `Skip()` and `Take()`

```
List<char> items = new List<char>() { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E' };
var result =  items.Take(items.Count() - 2).Concat(items.Skip(items.Count() - 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try another approach with [`List.RemoveAt(int)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cw9x18z(v=vs.110).aspx) where `int` is `index` you want to remove.

```
items_split.RemoveAt(items_split.Count - 2);
```

Answer (score -2):

This option takes advantage of the `Where` overload that takes an index, and use it to skip the next-to-last index.

```
var count = items_split.Count();
items_split.Where((item, index) => index != count -2)
```

Note, though, that this will call `Count` to get the total count, which will result in an iteration of the IEnumerable, and then a second iteration with `Where`. You might want to get a concrete, materialized collection first.

This might seem to defeat the point of using an `IEnumerable` in the first place, but remember, if your logic asks for the next-to-last, it means that you *have to get to the end of the collection* to *know* that it's the next to last.

Comment: that's a copy of Dmitry Bychenko's answer

Comment: You're right, I didn't notice his first solution, only his longer, second one